# Scipy spectogram message '<=' not supported between instances of 'complex' and 'complex'

Tags: python-3.x, spectrogram

I have a very short timeseries of 1200 samples and I am trying to produce a spectrogram. While the computation is done successfully, I get an error message while plotting.

Here is my timeseries :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVxOG.png)

Here is the code :

```
f, t, Sxx = signal.spectrogram(x)
plt.pcolormesh(t, f, Sxx)
plt.ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.xlabel('Time [sec]')
plt.show()
```

Here is the error message :

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/panos/anaconda3/envs/pycharm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py",
> line 3326, in run_code
>     exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)   File "<ipython-input-2-a4e2fa578405>", line 1, in <module>
>     runfile('/home/panos/Dropbox/Science/Projects/Flyworld/Computational
> attempts/pycharm/code_from_collaborations/Nicole_Vindice/create_frequency_plots.py',
> wdir='/home/panos/Dropbox/Science/Projects/Flyworld/Computational
> attempts/pycharm/code_from_collaborations/Nicole_Vindice')   File
> "/snap/pycharm-professional/173/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_umd.py",
> line 197, in runfile
>     pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script   File
> "/snap/pycharm-professional/173/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py",
> line 18, in execfile
>     exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)   File "/home/panos/Dropbox/Science/Projects/Flyworld/Computational
> attempts/pycharm/code_from_collaborations/Nicole_Vindice/create_frequency_plots.py",
> line 125, in <module>
>     plt.pcolormesh(t, f, Sxx)   File "/home/panos/anaconda3/envs/pycharm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py",
> line 2751, in pcolormesh
>     **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}), **kwargs)   File "/home/panos/anaconda3/envs/pycharm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py",
> line 1589, in inner
>     return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)   File "/home/panos/anaconda3/envs/pycharm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py",
> line 6169, in pcolormesh
>     collection.autoscale_None()   File "/home/panos/anaconda3/envs/pycharm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/cm.py",
> line 393, in autoscale_None
>     self.norm.autoscale_None(self._A)   File "/home/panos/anaconda3/envs/pycharm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/colors.py",
> line 953, in autoscale_None
>     self.vmin = A.min()   File "/home/panos/anaconda3/envs/pycharm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py",
> line 32, in _amin
>     return umr_minimum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims, initial) TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'complex' and 'complex'
```

Answer (score 1):

i got the exact same error message when my array was of type object and not float. If you do `x= np.array(x, dtype=float)` the problem should be solved.